# ESLint Flow linting not working with WebStorm and babel-eslint parser

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

I am trying to use ESLint to enforce some flow rules to the linting procedure but ESLint only reports non-flow errors.

I used this guide: [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#configuration)

My `.eslintrc.json` file is the following :

```
{
"extends": ["airbnb-base", "plugin:flowtype/recommended"],
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"plugins": [
    "import",
    "flowtype"
],
"rules": {
    "flowtype/boolean-style": [
        2,
        "boolean"
    ],
    "flowtype/define-flow-type": 1,
    "flowtype/delimiter-dangle": [
        2,
        "never"
    ],
    "flowtype/generic-spacing": [
        2,
        "never"
    ],
    "flowtype/no-primitive-constructor-types": 2,
    "flowtype/no-weak-types": 2,
    "flowtype/object-type-delimiter": [
        2,
        "comma"
    ],
    "flowtype/require-parameter-type": 2,
    "flowtype/require-return-type": [
        2,
        "always",
        {
            "annotateUndefined": "never"
        }
    ],
    "flowtype/require-valid-file-annotation": 2,
    "flowtype/semi": [
        2,
        "always"
    ],
    "flowtype/space-after-type-colon": [
        2,
        "always"
    ],
    "flowtype/space-before-generic-bracket": [
        2,
        "never"
    ],
    "flowtype/space-before-type-colon": [
        2,
        "never"
    ],
    "flowtype/type-id-match": [
        2,
        "^([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+Type$"
    ],
    "flowtype/union-intersection-spacing": [
        2,
        "always"
    ],
    "flowtype/use-flow-type": 1,
    "flowtype/valid-syntax": 1
},
"settings": {
    "flowtype": {
        "onlyFilesWithFlowAnnotation": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem solved.I had to create the Webstorm babel file watcher as the last step of the procedure.